# Why does the iii chord function as a tonic chord if it has a leading tone?

Tags: chords

I am learning chord functions in major scales and supposedly the iii chord has a tonic function. however, the chord has a leading tone so shouldn't it be considered a dominant chord?

Comment: Since it's the relative minor of that V chord, maybe. But when one considers Imaj7, iii is 3/4 of the way there.

Comment: What do you mean by leading tone?  Its own?  Or the LT of the key? The iii is a suitable  sub for the I and creates the Maj7, this is probably why you said it has an LT.  But it is also the rel min of the V as Tim stated.  It can actually serve as a sub for both.

Comment: Maybe according to some theory, the emperor has clothes. But in reality the emperor has no clothes and the iii chord doesn't end a tune like a I chord does. :)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is from [German theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(music)#German_functional_theory).

I don't know that theory well, but apparently the mediant chord can have both tonic and dominant function. The reason would be the overlapping tones of the tonic (`^3` and `^5`) and dominant (`^5` and `^7`) chords.

My way of reconciling the leading tone `^7` being in a non-dominant chord (and also the dominant `^5` is in the mediant) is two-fold:

- the `^3` degree has its basic identity as a member of the tonic chord
- the absence of `^4` - which could provide a dominant seventh - makes the chord less emphatically a dominant.

In other words the real dominant identity is `TI` & `FA` (in solfege) or scale degrees `^7` & `^4`. It may seem ironic but `^5` isn't so critical a factor, but keep in mind `^5` is in the tonic chord too; clearly not a dominant in that case. `TI` & `RE` make a good dominant. You might put it like this: the leading tone `TI` and the absence of potential tonic tones - for practical purposes `FA` or `RE` - make a clear dominant. Then `SOL` or `^5` provides... I suppose tonal stability.

Having said that I thought the German theory treated the mediant chord as a dominant and the submediant as a tonic. Using the English terminology of the Wikipedia page the *relative* relations of `I/vi` and `V/iii` are somehow more fundamental that the *counter-relative* relationship of `I/iii`.

I don't know how that theory is actually applied in analysis. I learned American theory where all seven scale degrees are discrete chords. I'm not sure how a analysis case is made for the mediant being either dominant (*Dominantparallele*) or tonic (*Tonika-Gegenparallele*.)